# Is it possible set up re-write rules for charles proxy from Command Line

Tags: http, proxy, charles-proxy

I'm trying to automate the set-up of re-write rules for charles proxy, I went through the documentation but I could not figure out a solution to automate this.
Please let me know if it is possible to set-up the re-write rules from CLI and are there any mechanisms to automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no proper cli, but you can access the control.charles browser interface via curl or a different tool.  Check out http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/web-interface/

I've used something like `curl -x 127.0.0.1:${CHARLESPORT} http://control.charles/${ENDPOINT}`

Sorry this response is so late.

Comment: Hello I am interested . How do you then view the SOAP requests after it's been done through charles proxy in a command line?

Comment: anyone know of a way to programmatically install Charles root certificate?